ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intel_extension_for_pytorch' 2.1
Example code from intel
import torch
import torchvision
import intel_extension_for_pytorch as ipex

LR = 0.001
DOWNLOAD = True
DATA = 'datasets/cifar10/'

transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
    root=DATA,
    train=True,
    transform=transform,
    download=DOWNLOAD,
)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset=train_dataset,
    batch_size=128
)

model = torchvision.models.resnet50()
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=LR, momentum=0.9)
model.train()

model, optimizer = ipex.optimize(model, optimizer=optimizer)
# Uncomment the code below to enable beta feature `torch.compile`
# model = torch.compile(model, backend="ipex")

for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(data)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(batch_idx)

torch.save({
    'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
    'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
}, 'checkpoint.pth')

print("Execution finished")

error same as conda and venv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\aspir\Desktop\Work\python\YOLOv8\test.py", line 3, in 
import intel_extension_for_pytorch as ipex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intel_extension_for_pytorch'
enter image description here
How to fix this error?
